# How can matter and anti-matter coexist in a meson?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter, quarks, mesons

Whilst learning about the nature of subatomic particles, I came along a pion zero meson. What really stumbled me was that the quark configuration of the particles was up and anti-up or down and anti-down (strange and anti-strange). My question is why don't the quarks annihilate and how would a particle like that be created?

Comment: They _do_ annihilate, that's why the particles decay, typically in less than a nanosecond.

Comment: @knzhou Oh wow. Thank you very much! However, how would one be created?

Comment: @knzhou Looks like an answer to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matter and antimatter to annihilate, all the [quantum numbers characterizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)  the two annihilating components have to add up to zero, so only same type can annihilate: proton-antiproton, electron-positron.

At the quark level [for mesons](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/meson.html) it is just the $π^0$

[image: pi0]

where quark and antiquark can match and annihilate, leaving at first order the two photon decay channel.

> However, how would one be created

It is created in primary interactions when the quantum numbers of quarks are matched up , depending on the probability of generating the particles.  The charged mesons decay with the weak interaction, the $π^0$ quarks interact electromagnetically and lead to annihilation.

[An example of a Feynman diagram](http://inspirehep.net/record/779705) where a  $π^0$ can appear is below in the decay of a D meson:

[image: Ddecay]

Comment: In this site https://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm there is a pi0 seen in a bubble chamber by the pair productiion of the decaying two photons.